# Token google analytics and relationship webPropertyId / profilId

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, access-token

I am currently developing a dashboard with Google Analytics API, which will be accessible website back office. I realized this during this developing javaScript I block on 2 things:

The first is the authentication must be transparent to the user via the use of a token.

In my approach I utlise OAuth2 of the API by generating a token with the playground for this token to be valid

I join my code

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var CLIENT_SECRET ='XXX...';
        var ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXX...';
        var REFRESH_TOKEN ='XXXX....';
        var EXPIRE_IN ='3600';
        var TOKEN_TYPE ='Bearer';
        var ACCESS_TYPE ='offline';
        var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
              clientid: CLIENT_ID,
              client_secret:CLIENT_SECRET,
              serverAuth: {
                  access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
                  refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
                  //token_type: TOKEN_TYPE,
                  //expires_in: EXPIRE_IN,
                  //access_type: ACCESS_TYPE,     
                  }
          });
```

After the validity of the data are more accessible with a 401 error (logical because the token is no longer valid)
or to my first question about how to obtain a valid token all the time?

My second question concerns the recovery of data I based on the recovery of the profile number (like many such works).
However SEVERAL of my sites using the tracking number (UA-XXXXXXXX-N).
Knowing that sites use this number is the posibility to find the profilId thanks to the tracking number and accountId that lion can deduct.

But I do not know how to arive.
Es that someone already out how to make this relationship ???

Pending your answers thank you in advance
(Sorry for the translation I utlise google translation)

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating using the playground  is a bad idea, and wont work for long. You are going to have to code your own authentication process here. It sounds like you want to do this with your own websites this your own data, I would normally recommend you use a service account.   A service account can be set up to authenticate without requiring the user to do anything.   While some people say that you can use a Service account with JavaScript, I don't feel that it is a secure solution, I also wonder if it is ok to do this under the current terms of service.   So my first recommendation to you is to look into using as service account with a server sided scripting language.  say PHP.     If you don't a user will have to authenticate and then they will only be seeing the information on there own website not your website.

Second how to find the Profile id:

The first and probably easiest option would be to just go to the admin section of Google analytics and find your profile id there.  If you are looking for a way of doing this programmatically you, I would use the [account summaries report from the Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountSummariesGuide) this will give you a list of all of the accounts for the current authenticated user you can then scan that to find the profile ids you want.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
Compared to the playground you tell me that it's a bad idea I do not understand why? Because it allows me to test the access token in development mode.
But precisely seeks to transform this token obtained cooling, circulation so that it automatically.
Unless you have a better idea

Regarding the data of each site will display it's data are displayed in back office website. It is please I need profilId recovered via the tracking number.

Comment: The id you get from playground is meant for testing at anytime it can and will break. Use the account summary report to get your profile id

Comment: I am actually the playground is for testing as it has a limited lifespan. My initial question was how to automatically refresh token, or have an automatic connection to the API by rpoort the code I have already established.
Regarding Id profile I did not include the use account summary, would you a different example than this on documentation of analytics?